# Converting units in R

Tags: r, units-of-measurement

I would like to convert from imperial units to metric and vice versa in R.  How do I go about doing that?

If there is no current way of doing that, how can I create a package that would?

Comment: your_matrix * your_conversion_factor, no package necessary for this one.

Comment: `RcppGSL` and `RcppArmadillo` are two R packages interfacing with external libraries that provide physical constants.

Comment: @baptiste could you be more specific about the functions/features that these Rcpp* packages provide?

Comment: @David it's in the docs for their respective web page: [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#constants), and [GSL](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/gsl-ref.html#Physical-Constants). The Rcpp* packages provide access to those libraries from R.

Comment: Converting physical units is tricky. I wrote a [unit conversion library in Ruby](https://www.github.com/boris-s/sy), so I know you have to separately treat dimensions, quantities and units, prefixes and abbreviations, preferred units for quantities etc. It's not simple.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I know this is very late, but the package `measurements` has a function `conv_unit()` that may be what you're looking for. You enter the imperial value you have, what unit you're converting from (e.g. 'ft') and what you want to convert to (e.g. 'km'). It has a variety of different dimensions (not just length).

Answer (score 25):

Edit: There is now an encyclopedic units package: [NISTunits](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NISTunits/NISTunits.pdf)

The nature of the units may affect the presence or absence. In general I think, unfortunately, that @gsk3 is correct. There are some function in the 'Hmisc', 'gdata', and 'marelac' packages:

Setting a units attribute (for more than just time objects):
http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/Hmisc/html/units.html

Medical:
http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/gdata/html/ConvertMedUnits.html

'marelac' Index (mostly specialized to oceanography)
http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/marelac/html/00Index.html

Temperature:
http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/marelac/html/convert_T.html

Barometric:
http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/marelac/html/convert_p.html

Package "dielectric" was mentioned by @Brian Diggs in an answer to a similar question:
[Link to 'constants' help page in package 'dielectric'](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/dielectric/html/constants.html)

I think those will provide examples of doing so and the function `package.skeleton` should help with the mechanics of package creation. I think the package would be a welcome addition.

Update: The 'udunits2' package was mentioned by Gabor Grothendieck in a similar question to rhelp July 23, 2012. It appears to require installation of a stand-alone OS-specific package of the same name. Without such installation you get a rather unhelpful error message:

```
> ud.convert(1, "miles", "km")  
Error in ud.convert(x, "miles", "km") : 
  Units miles and km are not convertible
```

Comment: This is a useful list. As usual I tried `library(sos); findFn("{unit conversion}")`.  I thought that `ConvertMedUnits` answered the question before I realized it was specific to medical units ...

Comment: the `udunits2` package (and underlying software) is really powerful; on ubuntu, the package dependencies can be installed with `sudo apt-get install udunits-bin libudunits2-dev`. Then you can do things like `ud.convert(1, "miles/hr", "km/s")` and even `ud.convert(1, "Mg/ha/yr", "kg/m2/d")` and it has a large database of unit synonyms.

Comment: I have since installed this package and as of 2013 I haven't needed any standalone applications to use this function.

Answer (score 8):

There is a "new" R package called *units* today, that was built upon the *udunits2* R package, which is available a while ago.

Have a look to: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/units/vignettes/units.html#setting-units-unit-conversion

```
library(units)
(spd1 = 1:5 * with(ud_units, m/s))
##Units: m/s
##[1] 1 2 3 4 5

(spd2 = 1:5 * with(ud_units, km/h))
#Units: km/h
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5

spd1 + spd2                   # automatic conversion
#Units: m/s
#[1] 1.277778 2.555556 3.833333 5.111111 6.388889

spd1 * spd2                   # unit derivation
#Units: km*m/h/s
#[1]  1  4  9 16 25

spd1 * 10 * with(ud_units, s) # unit simplification
#Units: m
#[1] 10 20 30 40 50

spd1 + 10 * with(ud_units, s) # error checking
#Error in `units<-.units`(`*tmp*`, value = list(numerator = "m", denominator = "s")) : 
cannot convert s into m/s
```

Comment: This got even better: `spd2 = 1:5 %>% set_units(mile)`, then `spd2 %>% set_units(km)` results in: `Units: [km]
[1] 1.609344 3.218688 4.828032 6.437376 8.046720`

Answer (score 7):

There is the `unit()` and `convertUnit()` functions in the **grid** package for specifying different length and dimension units.  That may do what you want, or give you a place to start if not.

Comment: looks like the [grid package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/grid) has been archived

Comment: @David, the `grid` package is no longer on CRAN because it is now one of the packages that installs with R, no need for a separate download from CRAN.

Comment: @GregSnow is that so? I don't see `unit` or `convertUnit` without loading any packages

Comment: @MichaelChirico, there is a difference between installing a package and loading a package.  Yes you still need to load the grid package to use unit and convertUnit, but you do not need to install the grid package separately from R.

Answer (score 6):

The [`udunits2`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/udunits2/index.html) package does just that. It wraps the powerful [UDUNITS library](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/units/index.html):

```
udunits2::ud.convert(1, "mi", "km")
## [1] 1.609344
```

On top of that, the [`units`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/units/index.html) package (work in progress) aims at providing a type-safe system for doing arithmetics with units:

```
with(ud_units, 1 * mi + 2 * km)
## 2.242742 mi
with(ud_units, 100 * km / (2 * h))
## 50 km/h
with(ud_units, 1 * mi + 2 * lb)
## Error: cannot convert lb into mi
```