# universal constants in R

Tags: r, statistics

This is going to sound like a basic question but... How do I use universal constants with R?

I was used to being able to just write e or PI in matlab, and these variables were reserved for the universal constants. Are those available in R as well? How to access/use them?

Thanks

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8087407/269476

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`pi` (note the lowercase) is defined but `e` is not, although exp(1) is obviously available.

```
pi
# [1] 3.141593
```

The small number of built-in constants are described :

```
?Constants
```

It would be possible to cure this lack-of-e problem with this code:

```
e <- exp(1)
lockBinding("e", globalenv())
e
#[1] 2.718282
e <- 2.5
#Error: cannot change value of locked binding for 'e'
```

(Thanks to Hadley for illustrating this in a different SO thread.)
You probably also should go to:

```
?NumericConstants
```

Where you will read among other things:  "A numeric constant immediately followed by i is regarded as an imaginary complex number."

The other important constants are `TRUE` and `FALSE`, and while `T` and `F` can be used in a clean session, `T` and `F` are not reserved and can be assigned other values, which will then provoke difficult to debug errors, so their use is deprecated. (Although, I suppose one could also use the `lockBinding` strategy on them as well.)

There are a few character "constants", such as the 26 item character vectors: `letters`, `LETTERS`, as well as 12 months in your locale: `month.abb` and `month.name`. The Greek letters (lower and uppercase) and some math notation can be accessed via methods described in `?plotmath`.

The `state.name` and `state.abb` mentioned by Tyler below are actually part of the  (USA) `state` dataset in the "datasets" package which is loaded by default:

```
library(help="datasets")
```

If you see an example that uses the `cars`, `chickwts`, `iris` or any of the other dataframes in "datasets", as many `help()` examples do, these objects can be assumed to be available on any R user's machine.

Comment: Note that locking a binding in the global environment does not prevent one from masking the value in another environment. e.g. `f <- function() { T <- FALSE; T }; f()` runs without error or warning and returns `FALSE` even if `T <- TRUE` in the global environment and has been locked there.

Comment: In addition to the constants described in ?Constants there's also state names and abbreviations with `state.name` & `state.abb`