# How to get the Planck constant in R?

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to find the the basic constants in R statistics but have not been able to do it.

I actually need the reduced Plack constant but I can get it myself (division by 2*pi) if I can get Planck constant.

However, it also exists in the system, please answer.

OS: Debian 8.5
R: 3.3.1

Comment: Depending what units you want it in (it is not dimensionless), you can just define it easily. E.g. `Planck = 6.626070040e−34` (in J s). The only built in constants in R are LETTERS, letters, month.abb, month.name, and pi

Comment: Related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214781

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(ChargeTransport)

# Return the Planck constant in J.s
universalConstants["h","Value"]

# Return the Planck constant in eV.s
Joule2electronVolt(universalConstants["h","Value"])
```

If you want directly the Angular Planck constant:

```
# in J.s
universalConstants["hbar","Value"]

# in eV.s
Joule2electronVolt(universalConstants["hbar","Value"])
```

Comment: if you see the dataset `universalConstants`, you also have the reduced one directly. I'll edit my answer, so that you can consider accepting it if it satisfies you.