# Converting Height Measurements from Imperial to Metric units

Tags: r

I've got data that, for the most part, reports height in centimeters, but with the occasional value (due to different sites, etc.) in inches and feet. So, for example, the data might look like:

```
Height
162
148
153
5' 3"
147
6' 0"
182
```

Clearly, this is a problem for parsing the data, let alone using it. Is there a clean programatic way to convert the Imperial units into their metric counterparts within R?

I can find a number of packages like `measurements` that appear to be able to handle unit conversions, but nothing seems to clearly address the weird hybrid of both feet and inches.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214781/converting-units-in-r). You just need to extract wanted values (probably using `grep`)

Comment: Can those voting to close due to broadness suggest a way to narrow the scope? It's unclear to me *how* the question is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a custom function, knowing the feet-cm conversion equation:

```
height <- c(162,148,153,"5' 3",147,"6' 0",182)
#[1] "162"  "148"  "153"  "5' 3" "147"  "6' 0" "182" 

my_conversion <- function(x, costant = 2.54) {

  find_feet <- !is.na(str_match(x, "'")) # we find which values are not in cm

  x[find_feet] <- gsub(" ", "", gsub("'", ".", x[find_feet])) #subsitute ' with . - and remove white spaces
  x <- as.numeric(x)

  feet <- floor(x[find_feet]) # feet 
  inch <- (x[find_feet] - feet) * 10 # inches


  x[find_feet] <- ((feet * 12) + inch) * costant # here we do the conversion feet-cm
  x
}

my_conversion(height)
#[1] 162.00 148.00 153.00 160.02 147.00 182.88 182.00
```

As long as all your feet values have the `'`, we can use that to find them, subsitute it with a `.`, then do the conversion: `cm = inches * 2.54`.

As an example:

```
5' 3 -> 5.3 -> [(5*12) + 3] * 2.54 = 160.02
```

Comment: 5' 3" is not 5.3 feet though...

Comment: update should be ok now. again thank you.