# Convert and represent the data in different unit system in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I am plotting various plots in the shiny app that I have developed, the raw dataset that I have, have all the data points in meters, for eg. one of my raw data set looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(X = c(0.000000000000,4.99961330240E-005,9.99922660480E-005,0.000149988399072,0.00019998453209, 0.000249980665120,0.000299976798144,0.000349972931168,0.000399969064192,0.000449965197216,0.000499961330240,0.000549957463264,0.000599953596288,0.000649949729312,0.000699945862336,0.000749941995360,0.000799938128384,0.000849934261408,0.000899930394432,0.000949926527456,0.000999922660480,0.00104991879350,0.00109991492653,0.00114991105955),
Y = c(0.00120303964354,0.00119632557146,0.00119907223731,0.00120059816279,0.00119785149693,0.00119876705222,0.00119327372051,0.00118900112918,0.00118930631428,0.00119174779504,0.00119113742485,0.00119541001617,0.00119815668203,0.00119052705466,0.00119205298013,0.00118930631428,0.00119174779504,0.00119388409070,0.00118778038881,0.00122287667470,0.00122684408094,0.00122623371075,0.00122867519150,0.00122379222999))
```

My attempt to plot:

```
g <- ggplot(data =  df) + theme_bw() +
        geom_point(aes_string(x= df[,1], y= df[,2]), colour= "red", size = 0.1)
    ggplotly(g)
```

And the plot looks like this:
[image]

What I want:

The data that I have in the datafile is in meters, but on the plot, I need Y-axis data to be shown in Micrometer and X-axis data to be shown in Millimeter. And the `dataframe` that I have illustrated above is just a small part of my actual `dataframe`. In the actual `dataframe`, data is very big.

Is there any way we can do this automatically without having the user to change the units manually?

In the end, I want 'Y' values to be multiplied by 10^6 and 'X' value to be multiplied by 10^3 in order to convert them into micrometers and millimeters respectively.

Comment: could you do `y = df[,2] * 10^6` ?

Comment: Yes, I can do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting units in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214781/converting-units-in-r)

Comment: No, It does not.

Answer (score 0):

I got two possible answers to my question:

1st is:

```
g <- ggplot(data =  df) + theme_bw() +
     geom_point(aes_string(x= df[,1]*10^3, y= df[,2]*10^6), colour= "red", size = 0.1)
     ggplotly(g)
```

2nd is:

```
M <- data.frame(x= df[,1]* 10^3, y= df[,2]* 10^6)

g <- ggplot(data =  M) + theme_bw() +
     geom_point(aes_string(x= M[,1], y= M[,2]), colour= "red", size = 0.1)
     ggplotly(g)
```